# confusing on java overriding vs polymorphism

Tags: polymorphism, overriding

I don't know if my question is related to overriding or polymorphism hence looking forward for someone advise.

Refer to the following coding,

```
    Father f=new Father();
    f.eat();             // display father's eat()
    Son s=new Son();
    s.eat();             // display Son's eat()
    Father x=new Son();
    x.eat();             // display Son's eat()
```

It is learned that

```
Son s=new Son();
        s.eat();
```

and

```
Father x=new Son();
        x.eat();
```

would display the same result, then I wonder why some tutorial are mentioned about using

```
Father x=new Son();
            x.eat();
```

instead of using

```
Son s=new Son();
            s.eat();
```

directly?

Answer (score 0):

In practice it is very common, that you don't use a class with it's real type (like Son in this case), but rather with one of it's super-classes (like Father in this case) or with one of it's interfaces (like Serializable class if it would have).

It is a very useful in polymorph languages like java that you don't need to know the real class, you can use it simply as a more generic one. For example, if you would draw shapes, you would hold them in a 'List<Drawable>' drawables' list, where

```
interface Drawable {
   //drawes the shape on the screen
   public void drawMe();
}
```

and there would be implementation classes of it like Rectange or Triangle.

Now, in your 'business logic' you don't want to know about the details of Rectangles or Triangles or any further shapes, the only thing you need to know, that this class implements the Drawable interface, so you can call a 'drawMe' method on it, so you can go through the list items like this

```
for(Drawable d: drawables) {
  d.drawMe();
}
```

I hope i could give some insight on this :)